# OS X Mavericks lost my mail folders!

Tags: mail.app, macos

After loading Mavericks it appears one of my mail folders, a key folder holding tax data has become completely borked.  As you can see from the attached image I have duplicate home folders.  I have already tried to rebuild this folder with no luck.  Any other ideas?

[image: .mbox list]

Posted @ Apple:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5494468

Comment: No backups I assume? Are you using IMAP or POP3?

Comment: I have backups, but I assumed I could merge them. is that not possible?

Comment: Previously, the only way to get even your own current mail folders / boxes back into Mail was to Import, one by one. Then Move the emails into the appropriate folders/mailboxes. Perhaps that still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb, use Time Capsule = Problem Solved.

I ended up migrated to Fastmail.fm => Away from Google.